# How to move to the foot of the web page dynamically

Tags: javascript, asp.net, focus, postback

I have been asked to move the focus of the web page to the bottom of the page from the click of a button. I've tried using Focus() but that doesn't seem to work, which I think is something to do with the Postback.

Does anyone have any other ideas how to do this?

Comment: so the button posts back, and then you want a different control focused when the page is reloaded after the post back? Or do you not even need the post back, the button should just change the focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an anchor (A tag) just above the footer (or at the top of the footer content), and assign a name to it; e.g.

```
<a name="footer"></a>
```

This will not be visible. However, it allows you to add `#footer` to the URL and the browser will scroll down to it. For example, add another link:

```
<a href="#footer">see footer</a>
```

---

Test how it works on this example:

[How to move to the foot of the web page dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114919/how-to-move-to-the-foot-of-the-web-page-dynamically/9115063#9115063)

Notice `#9115063` in the URL above.

If you look at the source of this page, close to the top of this answer, you'll find this:

```
<a name="9115063"></a>
```